# How to iterate with PHP through HTML DOM with xPath

Tags: php, html, xpath

I'm looking for a way to step in and out a DOMNodeList.
When my search hit a specific element the next element is located at another level.
In detail:

```
<tr>
  <td>
    <div class="category">
      <a>Headline:</a>
    </div>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>
    <div class="cdata">
      <span>Article to the title</span>
    </div>
  </td>
</tr>
```

My work so far:

```
$xpath = new DomXPath($dom);

$nodes = $xpath->query("//tr/td/div[@class='category']/a");

header("Content-type: text/plain");

foreach ($nodes as $i => $node) {
  echo "Node($i): " . ltrim($node->nodeValue) . "\n";
  if (ltrim($node->nodeValue) == 'Headline:')
  {
    // how can I fetch the nodeValue in the next TR
    echo "Parent: " . $node->parentNode->parentNode->parentNode->nodeValue . "\n";
  }
}
```

So until now I haven't figured out how to iterate 3 times up to the next "TR" and from there go down to the next DIV with a class ".cdata".

Comment: Not an answer, because I'm a bit of newbie at this, but I use jquery to make stepping through html elements easier. That's what it's for in many cases.

Comment: @ssaltman jquery is great for client-side dom manipulation, but OP is asking for server side.

Comment: Thank you, but yes, I would like to get a way to solve this on server-side.

Comment: right. never done that server side...is this because you are constructing a page or deconstructing a page? Just curious.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean with "constructing or deconstructing". My reason is to parse/read a page and search for given strings. When it exist I will save it and try to fetch the content belonging to that string/headline. But there I stuck at the moment because I dont't know how to move up and down from an actual element.